# why is apt-get not install mysql server 5.5

Tags: server, upgrade, mysql

I have mysql server 5.1 installed. I want to update it to 5.5 . I took a back up and uninstalled 5.1 using this command

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server*
```

when  I again used apt to install mysql server 5.5 it did not install it

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

It again installed the same version. Why is  apt not installing the never version

Comment: Sounds to me like 5.5 is not available in the apt repositories yet.

Comment: any idea when will it be added

Comment: I have 11.04 natty

Comment: mysql 5.5 is not available on Natty in the official repositories. But there's a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/ppa) that makes it available. You can try it if using PPA packages is an option to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since you are getting mysql 5.1, I believe you have Ubuntu 10.04.](https://launchpad.net/mysql-server)

From my understanding of how package releases work in Ubuntu, you will not have any newer version unless you find another repository which offers it, or install it manually yourself.

Once an Ubuntu version is released, new applications, and even newer versions of applications are not released for it. Updating to a another Ubuntu Version is the only way of having a newer version of packages from the **official repositories**.

Only security and bug fixes are released.